# Is there need to clear cache for layout change if cache already disbabled in magento 2

Tags: magento2, category

I am changing some category view page layout and cache is disabled but wont affecting anything on fronted so i want know Do i need to clear cache?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Clearing cache is not required after disabling the cache.

**May be something wrong in your layout or some other module overriding your layout changes**